# create an instance of the abstract class DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

in an Angular component we can inject DomSanitizer and use it.

```
@component({..})
export class myComponent{
 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
  //now we can use this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(..)
}

}
```

but how to use DomSanitizer without injecting it in the constructor?

```
//this is not a class, so it doesn't contain a constructor() 

export function keepHtml(value: string){
 sanitizer = new DomSanitizer(); //error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
 return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}
```

I don't want to import `DomSanitizer` into my class, and then pass it to keepHtml() as a second parameter.

I want the whole implementation done inside the functions file.

also I don't want to convert the function keepHtml() into a class method.

Comment: What stops you from using the injection?

Comment: because I don't use it inside a component, the function keepHtml() is implemented in a separate file ./functions which has no constructor. @AntonRusak

Comment: You may put the function into a service. Services allow injection.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use the internal implementation of DomSanitizer like this:

```
import { ɵDomSanitizerImpl } from '@angular/platform-browser/';

export function keepHtml(value: string){
 const sanitizer = new ɵDomSanitizerImpl(document);
 return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}
```

However this is not a good way to go. The internal implementation might change in future and break your code.

Comment: error:  Expected 1 arguments, `constructor(_doc: any);`  An argument for '_doc' was not provided.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to set `document` as a parameter. Try the edited code.

Answer (score 3):

Using a service for this (Anton Rusak's reply on the original post) is the way to go, and allows reusability.

Quick example would be as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceUsedForWhatever {

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  sanitizeResource(multimediaResource) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(multimediaResource);
  }
}
```

And in any component, import the service and use it as follows:

```
mediaToSanitize = this.dataService.sanitizeResource(originalMedia);
```

It could even be improved by adding a switchcase listening to a second parameter called, for example, mediaType, so that the function could use other methods such as bypassSecutiryTrustHtml or bypassSecurityTrustUrl.

Edit: the author did indicate they did not want to use it as an injection because it was probably being used in a common /functions file to extend methods to other components, and I get that approach. But chances are that your project has, or could have, a generic Service that does stuff that other components or even Services can benefit from (such as getting/setting a token). The example above would go nicely with a service like that.